# Configuring overlay background colour for ContentDialog

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm writing an app for the universal windows platform using the dark theme and I've noticed that although I've correctly set the requested theme to dark when I display a modal dialog using the `ContentDialog` class the overlay lightens the overall page rather than darkening it.

Before dialog displayed:

[image: Screenshot of page before overlay]

With dialog displayed:

[image: Screenshot of page after overlay displayed]

Since there isn't a property on `ContentDialog` to control the overlay how do I override the colour being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some experimentation I've found that the brush being used to control the colour of the overlay that a `ContentDialog` is displayed above is `SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseMediumBrush`rather than the more likely looking `ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush`.

By inspecting the default theme definitions it emerges that both light and dark themes set this brush to the colour resource `SystemBaseMediumColor` which on the light theme is `#99000000` and on the dark theme is `#99FFFFFF`. This results in the overlay darkening the light theme and lightening the dark theme.

Since `SystemBaseMediumColor` is references by other brush definitions such as those used for inactive pivot titles it's necessary to override `SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseMediumBrush` rather than the colour it references solely for the dark theme.

To do this we need to redefine the brush in a resource theme dictionary in `App.xaml` or in a resource XAML file merged into `App.xaml`along the lines of:

```
<Application>

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">

                    <SolidColorBrush 
                        x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseMediumBrush" 
                        Color="#99000000"
                        />

                </ResourceDictionary>

           </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

       </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Comment: Very good job, now that we are in details, have you seen when the Window of the App is resized has a blank white background and is below the root frame (because I set an Image in the root frame). Any idea to change that color? I think is internal. Apart I have to see how to dismiss the contentdialog when the border ir touched I understand I will have to edit the template.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code for the accepted answer, but changing the color of this brush worked for me... "SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Maybe because i am using Anniversary Edition as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396246/changing-the-overlay-background-color-for-contentdialog)

Also make sure your resource dictionary key matches the theme you are using. I was using the "Light" theme, so I changed the Resource dictionary x:key to this...

```html
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below code.**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the Overlay background for content Dialog
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subTree">Content Dialog reference</param>
    public static void SetContentDialogOverlay(UIElement subTree)
    {

        var hostparent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(subTree);
        var rect = FindVisualChild<Rectangle>(hostparent);
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rect.Opacity = 0.7;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the child element from UIContainer
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="depObj"> Dependency Reference </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childItem != null) return childItem;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now, Call the above method on your code behind like this----

```
   // Based upon your access modifier i.e. public/private or protected
    SetContentDialogOverlay(this);
```

Here, "this" represent the Content Dialog reference or you can pass the object reference of the ContectDialog.

Hope, this will help you to change the color of the Overlay.
Happy Coding .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code in App.xaml. It works for me properly.

`<Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#00000000" />
    </Application.Resources>`