# ContentDialog - Remove / change color around - Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, windows-10, uwp

I have a `ContentDialog` on my Universal Windows Application. When are showed, the space around it, is white with transparency. If change opacity, changed all `ContentDialog` opacity.

Someone know to remove or change color around `ContentDialog`?

Thanks

Comment: I think a describing picture would say more then 1000 words.

Comment: Yea, looked at the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx) and don't see anything in there that jumps out as what you might be talking about. Can you show what you mean?

Comment: Override SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseMediumBrush.  reference ==>    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159658/configuring-overlay-background-colour-for-contentdialog

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Mask color`,which is white or black, is related to your `Request Theme`.

Try to change the `Request Theme` of your `Content Dialog` or your Page.