# Changing the Overlay background color for ContentDialog

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

For my UWP app, I want to override the default theme of the background color of the screen around the content dialog when it opens. I tried doing what's mentioned in this answer but it didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159659/2858235

My OS build # is 10586. I read somewhere that this solution is no more working for builds equal and above 10586. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, my SDK version is 14393 (Anniversary) and the SolidColorBrush resource to override is `SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush` (that's a mouthful!).

Comment: Works well. I have a question, is there any documentation that explains all the default Themes which exist and which one is for what purpose? Also, is SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush specific for ContentDialog or it may affect any other place of the application?

Comment: The default styles and templates for most controls are documented on MSDN. They are also defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.?????.0\Generic\generic.xaml" for each installed SDK version. That resource may be used for other things, I'm not sure. Unfortunately I couldn't narrow down a ContentDialog-specific resource.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for posting the path to generic.xaml file. I will see if I can verify the places where SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush is being used.